# Shell Script to Toggle Between Two Commands

Tags: scripts

I need help creating a shell script to toggle between two commands.
When it is run `command1` is executed then if it is run again it executes `command2` and so on...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One good way of accomplishing this is for the script to create a blank "configuration file":

- The 1st time the script runs, it sees the file doesn't exist, creates it, and runs `command1`.
- The 2nd time the script runs, it sees the file does exist, deletes it, and runs `command2`.
- The 3rd time the script runs, it sees the file doesn't exist, creates it, and runs `command1`.
- The 4th time the script runs, it sees the file does exist, deletes it, and runs `command2`.

And so forth.

Here's a script that does that:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This shell script is PUBLIC DOMAIN. You may do whatever you want with it.

TOGGLE=$HOME/.toggle

if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
    command1
else
    rm $TOGGLE
    command2
fi
```

Comment: A slight improvement would be a semaphore file (touch .xxx) for 'last command', with a known first choice.

Comment: @david6 You may want to post your own answer. It's not clear to me why that would be better, or how you intend to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

### *(As a complement to the [main answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/147091/925128))*

To make it display a message after running the commands, and also showing an icon - example for toggling touchpad off and on ([source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1750811#p1750811), also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/863750/925128)):

```
#!/bin/sh
# This shell script is PUBLIC DOMAIN. You may do whatever you want with it.

TOGGLE=$HOME/.toggle_touchpad

if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
    xinput disable 14
    notify-send -u low -i mouse --icon=/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/256x256/status/touchpad-disabled.png "Trackpad disabled"
else
    rm $TOGGLE
    xinput enable 14
    notify-send -u low -i mouse --icon=/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/256x256/devices/input-touchpad.png "Trackpad enabled"
fi
```

(in the above commands `14` is a variable to be identified with `xinput list`)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a file with your last command. Then when it is run again you read the file, and see which command was executed.