# Create a 'toggle keyboard shortcut' in ubuntu gnome 17.04

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there any way by command-line (no softwares) to set a keyboard shortcut to toggle between 2 commands using the same shortcut key combination. Actually, i wanted to toggle my mousepad when using mouse.

Comment: OK, and what command do you use to toggle the trackpad (or touchpad, not mousepad; the mousepad is what you put under a mouse)? This is possible, but the details will depend in your hardware, the name of your trackpad etc. Please [edit] your question and give us more details. Specifically, the output of the command `xinput list`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. First you need to identify your touchpad. Run `xinput list` (you might have to install `xinput` with `sudo apt install xinput` first). On my system, that shows:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M325                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So, my touchpad is called `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad`. Find out the name of yours and then modify this script accordingly:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Change this value to whatever your touchpad is called
touchpad='SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'

status=$(xinput  list-props "$touchpad" | grep "Device Enabled" | gawk '{print $NF}');

if (( $status==1 )); then
    xinput -set-int-prop "$touchpad" "Device Enabled" 8 0
else
    xinput -set-int-prop "$touchpad" "Device Enabled" 8 1
fi
```

Save that script as `~/bin/toggle_touchpad.sh` and then use your desktop environment's GUI to assign a shortcut to it. The shortcut will now run the script and toggle the touchpad as desired.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/863750/507051) is even more detailed, if you anybody has still troubles.